# TikZ semi transparent contiguous shapes with no gaps

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, transparency, wolfram-mathematica

**Short Question**:

The short question can be stated as follows: Is there a way to perfectly align filled (but possibly not drawn) shapes that completely cover contiguous areas?

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,crop=true,border=1pt]{standalone}
\definecolor[named]{Back}{cmyk}{0,.3,.94,0}
\definecolor[named]{Front}{cmyk}{0,1.0,.64,.34}
\tikzset{mmaF/.style={fill=Front!#1,draw=Front!#1,
    line width=.04pt,opacity=1}}
\tikzset{mmaB/.style={line width=0.01pt,fill=Back!#1,   
    draw=Back!#1,opacity=.5}}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[transparency group]
    \draw[mmaF=50] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \draw[mmaB=90] (1,1) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \draw[mmaB=90] (-1,-1) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \draw[mmaB=90] (-1,1) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \draw[mmaF=88] (2,-1) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \draw[mmaB=90] (1,-1) rectangle ++(2,2);            
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Sample tikz polygons]

If you look closely, there are little doubly drawn lines over the center reddish polygon. If you change `draw=Back!#1` for `draw=none` in style `mmaB`, then you get little gaps instead of doubly drawn lines.

What makes this question hard is the fact that the *order of the polygons is important*. I can't simply group the mmaB style polygons into a `scope` with `opacity=.5,transparency group`. The reason is explained below, in the background story.

**Background Story**

Using Mathematica to compute polygons, I can draw things like this:

[image: A drawing in tikz, produced with mathematica]

For the curious, this is just some 10.000+ lines of simple tikz. Mathematica computes  the 3D->2D conversion, and gives an ordered collection of plane tikz shapes to be filled with either style `mmaF`-for front facing polygon- or `mmaB`-for back facing polygon.

However, I am having trouble when mixing with opacity:

[image: This time, with some semi transparent parts]

Where you can see the grid lines. Problem: how to remove the grid lines in the semi-transparent part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the question (my english :) )
I use `\path` instead of `\draw`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,crop=true,border=1pt]{standalone}
\definecolor[named]{Back}{cmyk}{0,.3,.94,0}
\definecolor[named]{Front}{cmyk}{0,1.0,.64,.34}
\tikzset{mmaF/.style={fill=Front!#1,opacity=1}}
\tikzset{mmaB/.style={fill=Back!#1, opacity=.5}}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[transparency group]
    \path[mmaF=50] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \path[mmaB=90] (1,1) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \path[mmaB=90] (-1,-1) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \path[mmaB=90] (-1,1) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \path[mmaF=88] (2,-1) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \path[mmaB=90] (1,-1) rectangle ++(2,2);            
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but artifacts are still there, whether you use `\path` or `\draw` or `\filldraw`. The four yellowish pieces should neither leave gaps nor overdraw at the "frontier".

Comment: To be more specific: your answer leaves a small, but visible gap between the four yellow pieces. My example in the question above shows overdrawing. I would like to remove both kind of artifacts, if possible.

Comment: @Koji Ok I see the problem with acrobat reader but not with skim or preview on a mac with OS X.

Comment: I _do_ see the problem with OS X's Preview, though I have to zoom in close enough.

Comment: The problem is important with acrobat with opacity =1 and .5 but seems to disappears with  opacity =1 and 1. With skim the problem is important with opacity =1 and 1. If' you draw the borders, the lines are one above the other. Now there are perhaps a problem with the viewers. The problem depends  of the zoom.

Comment: @Koji With my code and under the last OS X with pdflatex the problem appears only with acrobat.

Comment: I'll take @Altermundus answer: "it depends on the viewer", since I can't find any other reasonable explanation.